# SQL: Combining two query results that have a common column but each has its own specific unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm struggling to find the right approach to what I want to achieve.
So here's what I have:

Query A gives me the following result:

| TrainingID | totalPass |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

Query B gives me the following

| TrainingID | totalFail |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 9 |

The result I'd like to have is the following:

| TrainingID | totalPass | totalFail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | Null |
| 4 | 8 | Null |
| 6 | Null | 7 |
| 7 | Null | 9 |

I tried emulating an outer join in MySQL by combining left and right join with an union but the result is not quite what I want, but the closest I could get into. Perhaps my main issue is that I don't know a terminology to describe what is exactly this operation I'm trying to do so I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st query add a `NULL` column for `totalFail` and in the 2nd query add a `NULL` column for `totalPass`.
Use UNION ALL to get all rows and aggregate:

```
SELECT TrainingID,
       MAX(totalPass) AS totalPass,
       MAX(totalFail) AS totalFail
FROM (
  SELECT TrainingID, totalPass, NULL AS totalFail
  FROM QueryA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TrainingID, NULL, totalFail
  FROM QueryB
) t
GROUP BY TrainingID
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a47a4901015b8b798317f7389e1ff953).

Comment: this did exact the trick for me in MySQL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a full outer join. Here is an example:

```
declare @p table (TrainingID int,   totalPass int)
insert into @p
values
(2, 5)
,(3,    7)
,(4,    8)

declare @f table (TrainingID int,   totalFail int)

insert into @f
values
(2, 3)
,(6,    7)
,(7,    9)

select TrainingID = COALESCE(p.TrainingID,f.TrainingID)
    , totalPass = SUM(p.totalPass)
    , totalFail = SUM(f.totalFail)
from @p p
    full outer join @f  f on p.TrainingID=f.TrainingID
group by COALESCE(p.TrainingID,f.TrainingID)
```

Note:
COALESCE is a function that takes the first non-null value.

```
Result:

TrainingID  totalPass   totalFail
2              5          3
3              7          NULL
4              8          NULL
6              NULL       7
7              NULL       9
```

Comment: Based on your current data, you don't need the aggregation, but I thought I saw somewhere that you did need it.

Comment: Also note that you can coalesce the pass and fails to 0 to remove the nulls.

Comment: which engine is this for? For MySQL I can't really use OUTER JOIN, but I tried emulating through left and right joins and then I run into other errors like "can't reopen table" when trying to use the temp tables I created for my queries A and B (or p and f in your example). Also, I think the behaviour of the engines are a bit different in those functions as if I execute just a left join part of your query I get really weird results like displaying trainingID "1" in the result (we don't even have that value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select coalesce(a.trainingId, b.trainingId)
,a.totalPass
,b.totalPass
from (QueryA) a full outer join (queryB) b on (queryA.trainingId =    b.trainingId
```

Comment: The full outer join is what you are looking for.

Comment: you don't need sum since query a and query b don't have overlapping data columns and training id is unique in both queryA and queryB

Comment: I can't use the full outer join in MySQL. Trying to use a combination of right + left join to achieve that lead me into other errors as my temp tables being locked :(

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support `full join` -- which is what you want.  But you can do this without too much trouble using `union all`.  But let's define your queries using CTEs first:

```
with a as (
      . . .
     ),
     b as (
      . . .
     )
select trainingId, a.totalPass, b.totalFail
from a left join
     b
     using (trainingId)
union all
select trainingId, null, b.totalFail
from b left join
     a
     using (trainingId)
where a.trainingId is null;
```